# Data missing on belongs to many relation

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to get data from a Many to Many Relationship using Eloquent in Laravel. Every time I do this I get a `Data Missing` error.

I've tried the following to get the data:

```php
return  $workers = Worker::first()->workers_sub_categories;
```

```php
return $workers = Worker::with('workers_sub_categories')->get();
```

Both of these result in the `DataMissing` error.

The `Worker` model:

```php
protected $table = "workers";

protected $primaryKey = 'workers_id';

protected $fillable = [
    'workers_username', 'email', 'password', 'FK_cities_id',
    'FK_packages_id', 'workers_points', 'jwt', 'workers_img',
    'workers_lat', 'workers_lang', 'workers_phone_number',
    'workers_businessregister', 'workers_desc', 'remember_token',
    'workers_status', 'workers_verified', 'step', 'expiry_date', 'workers_created_at', 'workers_updated_at'
];

const CREATED_AT = 'workers_created_at';
const UPDATED_AT = 'workers_updated_at';

public function related_orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order', 'FK_workers_id', 'workers_id');
}

public function related_offers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Offer', 'FK_workers_id', 'workers_id');
}

public function related_comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment', 'FK_workers_id', 'workers_id');

}

public function worker_orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Order', 'orders_workers_status', 'FK_workers_id',
        'FK_orders_id')->withPivot('FK_categories_id', 'FK_sub_categories_id');
}

public function related_rates()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rate', 'FK_workers_id', 'workers_id');

}

public function related_city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\City', 'FK_cities_id', 'cities_id');

}

public function workers_sub_categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\SubCategory', 'workers_services', 'FK_workers_id',
        'FK_sub_categories_id');
}

public function setWorkersImgAttribute($file)
{
    if ($file) {
        $fileName = $this->createFileName($file);
        $this->originalImage($file, $fileName, 'worker/profile/original');
        $this->mediumImage($file, $fileName, 150, 150, 'worker/profile/meduim');
        $this->thumbImage($file, $fileName, 70, 70, 'worker/profile/thumbnail');
        $this->attributes['workers_img'] = $fileName;
    }
}

public function setWorkersBusinessRegisterAttribute($file)
{
    if ($file) {
        $fileName = $this->createFileName($file);
        $this->originalImage($file, $fileName, 'worker/business/original');
        $this->mediumImage($file, $fileName, 150, 150, 'worker/business/meduim');
        $this->thumbImage($file, $fileName, 70, 70, 'worker/business/thumbnail');
        $this->attributes['workers_businessregister'] = $fileName;
    }
}
```

The `SubCategories` model:

```php
protected $table = "sub_categories";

protected $primaryKey = 'sub_categories_id';

protected $fillable = [
    'sub_categories_img', 'sub_categories_status', 'FK_categories_id',
];

const CREATED_AT = 'sub_categories_created_at';
const UPDATED_AT = 'sub_categories_updated_at';

public function workers_categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Worker', 'workers_services', 'FK_sub_categories_id', 'FK_workers_id');
}

protected function getArrayableAttributes()
{
    foreach ($this->attributes as $key => $value) {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            $this->attributes[$key] = '';
        }
    }

    return $this->getArrayableItems($this->attributes);
}

public function related_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category', 'FK_categories_id', 'categories_id');
}

public function getSubCategoriesImgAttribute()
{
    return SiteImages_path('subcategory').'/thumbnail/'.$this->attributes['sub_categories_img'];
}
```

The database migration:

```php
$table->bigIncrements('workers_services_id');
$table->bigInteger('FK_workers_id')->unsigned();
$table->bigInteger('FK_sub_categories_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('FK_workers_id')->references('workers_id')
    ->on('workers')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('FK_sub_categories_id')->references('sub_categories_id')
    ->on('sub_categories')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

It's supposed to return all workers with pivot.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: InvalidArgumentException
Data missing

Comment: Is there a stacktrace that shows where the error is coming from?

Comment: it gives me error in carbon
Carbon\Carbon rawCreateFromFormat
…\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php559
52
Carbon\Carbon createFromFormat

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: http://alti.my-staff.net/Capture.PNG here it is

Comment: [link](http://alti.my-staff.net/Capture.PNG) here it is

Comment: What's the result of `dd(Worker::first()->workers_sub_categories[0]->getAttributes());`?

Comment: I knew the error the error was in created at and updated at in subcategory model they were null once i filled in the date it worked but I don't know why I used it null before and it was working fine do you know why?

Comment: No, that's hard to say.